# Why would an ADC produce square wave data from a sine wave signal?

Tags: analog, adc, signal-processing

I have a device that produces a 200Hz analog sine wave signal and reads the data in a time delay from the peak of the signal after X microseconds. When using an ADS1015 ADC to read the data at 100us intervals across the entire wavelength, I get a near perfect sine wave response. However when I substitute the ADS1015 for a MAX11612 (approx) I get a nearly square wave response.

Can anyone tell me why that might be happening? As an FYI, the signal appears as a true sine wave on an oscilloscope as well while using both chips. Here's an example of how the code reads the data:

- Sets delay time from the sine wave peak at 0us
- Reads data for 1 second (approx 200 samples) and averages data
- Increments delay time by 100us and re-reads sample

I'm stumped as to why one chip produces a near perfect sine wave data and the other a modified square wave data.  The square wave data has a very short rise/fall time and a flat peak and trough with only a very slight variation in response across the flat areas of the wave.

Anyone have any idea why this might be occurring?

[MAX1161X Datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11612-MAX11617.pdf)

[ADS1015 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1015.pdf)

Oscilloscope analog signal:
Blue segments are two readings at two delay times on a single wave of the yellow analog signal

[image: Oscilloscope analog signal]

ADS1015 data plot:

[image: ADS1015 Data Plot]

Unfortunately I don't have a sample pic of the MAX11612 data plot, but it looks very similar to the ADS1015 except that it is  much more squared off even though data is within range.

Comment: Data sheet links and schematic for both ADCs used are required.

Comment: The software you use to read and interpret the ADC results could also be to blame here.

Comment: Sounds like clipping. Compare the input voltage range of the two ADCs (if you need help, link their datasheets in the question. More likely : you are misreading the digital output format (offset binary vs 2's complement). Unlikely but possible : input level is so low that only the LSB is active : it'll look like a square wave. Waveform plots would help...

Comment: Datasheet links added
The software appears to be functioning normally.  ADC results are in line with the expected voltages
@user_1818839 I would also suspect clipping.  However the signal range is between 0 and 2.0 VDC and both ADC chips are powered by 3.3VDC with a range of -0.3VDC to 3.6VDC.  So I don't think that's the issue either.  I can change the analog signal anywhere from 100mV to 3.0V and I get the same odd squaring of the wave with the MAX11612 only.

Comment: Are you using the MAX's internal reference or supplying an external Vref? Are you sure you've configured the MAX's reference settings correctly in its setup register for the reference you're using?

Comment: You'll need to check the mode settings : mux channel, ref voltage, and output format (unipolar/bipolar). See 8.5.4 on the TI and pp.19,20 "Ref Volt" and "Transfer Functions"  on the Maxim

Comment: @brhans  Yes, in fact here's the link with the code that we worked out on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034027/how-do-i-read-data-via-i2c-from-a-max11613-chip-using-c-on-a-rpi-3b.  I'm just trying to simplify the issue here to the electronics side of the question.  Setup is 0x8E and config is 0x00.  You'll note from that we're using the internal reference and actually a differential AIN0/AIN1 bipolar reading and we are accounting for the twos complement.

Comment: If the signal exceeds VREF, what happens?  Is that when clipping takes over producing the roughly square wave?  I had tried using VDD as the reference, but found it to be problematic, but if that's the issue, then maybe the solution lies there?

Comment: A signal above Vref cannot be represented in the output data. What you get is anybody's guess, up to and including smoke.

Comment: @user_1818839 that makes absolute sense.  I'll change it back to use the VDD as the reference and give it a shot.  Thanks for the pointer.  I'll post back the results in a few days.

Comment: Over in your StackOverflow question you write that you're using the internal clock with setup byte 0xF0, but in a comment here you write "Setup is 0x8E". 0x8E selects the external clock mode (bit-3 is set).

Comment: That's correct. After some additional testing, we switched to the external clock.